# How to resume an idle workflow from any activity that induces idle

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow (WF 4.5) which is basically a series of questions. However, I need to be able to persist this workflow so that the user can resume at the last question he answered, or at any question before that one, so that he can change his answers.

For example, if the workflow has a total of 10 questions (question 1 to 10), and the user answered them up to question number 7, I want him to be able to choose which question he wants to resume up to question 7, which would allow him to choose any question from 1 to 7. If he chooses question 3, he will be able to give a new answer to question 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and continue up to question 10.

Is it possible to accomplish that through bookmarks? Could I create a different bookmark for each question, and even if the user is already at question 7 (with 7 bookmarks created up to this point), can I resume the workflow from the bookmark created at question 3, for example? If not, how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got your Question correctly 
but if you wanna go back to the any steps of the workflow you can do it by return to book Mark 
and you can add book mark in each step in your workflow 
actually in every step you waiting dta from user you will need a book mark so you can return where it's stopped 
wish the answer help you